# Fiware mqtt device limit

Tags: mqtt, device, sensors, fiware, fiware-orion

Is there any limit on the number of devices to be connected in fiware 3.7.0? Can we connect as many devices as we want?

I searched through the documentation and various sources, but I couldn't find any information on this subject

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard or predefined limit to this. In case of MQTT devices it will be your MQTT broker, along with your current infrastructure and configuration (i.e available file descriptors), which may impose a limit to the max number of devices.